# Make identity matrix in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, identity

I'm beginner student of python and tensorflow.

So I need some advice about tensor knowledge, or at least googling keyword

I want to do

```
import tensorflow as tf

grad = input_gradient # tensor Variable 
noise_scalar = tf.random_normal([1], stddev=stddev)[0]
grad_shape = grad.shape.as_list()

noise_mat = some_identity_matrix(grad_shape) # I don't know this

noise_mat = tf.scalar_mul(noise_scalar, noise_mat)
grad = tf.add(grad, noise_mat)
```

I don't know how to make identity matrix same size with input gradients shape, they have various sizes such as (1,) (5, 5) (5, 5, 1, 1) (5, 5, 1, 64) ...

With tf.eye(..) can make 1, 2 dimensional identity matrix, but not higher.
help me, please

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities, depending on the desired output:

1) use `batch_shape` argument, `tf.reshape` and potentially `tf.transpose`

```
ident = tf.eye(5, batch_shape=(3, 4)      # shape = (3, 4, 5, 5)
# switch axis 2 with axis 0
ident = tf.transpose(ident, (2, 1, 0, 3)) # shape = (5, 4, 3, 5)
```

2) use `tf.expand_dims` or `tf.reshape` in conjunction with `tf.tile`:

```
ident = tf.eye(5)                         # shape = (5, 5)
ident = tf.reshape(ident, (5, 1, 1, 5))   # shape = (5, 1, 1, 5)
# or: ident = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(ident, axis=1), axis=1)
ident = tf.tile(ident, (1, 4, 3, 1))      # shape = (5, 4, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Although I don't understand 3 or 4 dimensional identity matrix, tilling method has values to try. Thanks!

Comment: In the above examples, `ident[p, j, k, q] = 1 if p == q else 0` - i.e. its 1 if you're on the "diagonal" of axes 0 and 3, and the same across all of axes 1 and 2.